# "List iterators incompatible" while running

Tags: c++, visual-studio, list, visual-studio-2015, iterator

```
void GameLogic::isHit(int mousePressX, int mousePressY) 
{

for each(BallObject* ball in ballList) {
    for (it = ballList.begin(); it != ballList.end();)
    {
        bool isHit = ball->EvaluateHit(mousePressX, mousePressY);
        if (isHit == true)
        {
            mScore++;
            ballList.remove(ball);
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to remove ball from "ballList" while playing game via click on surface(ball should dissapear). Program is running correctly until click. When I click, it gives an error from the title. How does it right?

Comment: You're iterating twice over `ballList` (why?) and invalidating iterators as you  go.

Comment: remove the outer loop, then try `it = ballList.erase(it)` instead of `ballList.remove(ball)`

Comment: A for each or a ranged based for loop should not mutate the container but only the elements of the container.

Comment: `for each` is non standard VS2015 extension, which as I checked is also available for native C++ (with /ZW). Why not using standard c++? But back to the topic, you remove a ball from a list you are iterating, so it might cause UB - and debug mode is kind enough to give you assertion with such nice title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void GameLogic::isHit(int mousePressX, int mousePressY) 
{
    // iterate all the balls in the list...
    for (it = ballList.begin(); it != ballList.end();)
    {
        bool isHit = (*it)->EvaluateHit(mousePressX, mousePressY);

        if (isHit == true)
        {
            mScore++;
            // This invalidates iterators, and is linear in complexity
            // (it iterates the list too, but you're already doing that)
            // ballList.remove(ball);

            // erase the ball at this iteration, save off the result
            // so you can continue iterating
            it = ballList.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            // if the ball wasn't hit, increment the iterator normally
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```